# Why doesn't my slick slider appear in WordPress theme?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, slick.js

I am working on a WordPress website and I installed [TeamShowCase](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-team-showcase-and-slider/) plugin for it, and this plugin uses slick.js.
But problem is that my slider doesn't appear in my website.
I think there is conflict between slick and part of my theme.
Anyway you can see my website [here](http://step.mstfdn.org/#team).

Comment: I don't know the exact issues but please check @media (min-width: 768px)
.col-sm-12 {/* width: 100%; */}

Comment: can we see your slick js setup please because your image code is appearing but your images are not your slick code would be useful

Comment: how many slides do you have set up and how many are you sliding through  
infinite: true,
  slidesToShow: 3,
  slidesToScroll: 3
because it looks like your current setup may be trying to slide them all